# Problems with codecs using graph.add() of RDFLib

Tags: python, rdflib

I create a graph (RDFLib), in Python, with store "Oxigraph" indicating a path do store my graph, as we can see in the code below:

```
78    if os.path.exists(dirarqs + "\\g1_graph_dir"):
79        shutil.rmtree(dirarqs + "\\g1_graph_dir")
80    g1 = Graph(store="Oxigraph", identifier="http://g1.com")
81    g1.open(dirarqs + "\\g1_graph_dir")
 
91    g1.parse(narq1, format="xml", incremental=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

I must make some updates in the graph. When I try use the method `add` (line 113), I get a problem.

```
101    for subj, pred, obj in g1:
102        narq = subj.split("#")[0]
103        break
104    
105    for subj, pred, obj in g1:
106        subjx = subj.split("#")[-1].encode("latin-1")
107        predx = pred.encode("latin-1")
108        if narq in obj:
109            objx = Literal(obj.split("#")[-1]).encode("latin-1")
110        else:
111            objx = obj.encode("latin-1")
112        g1.remove((subj, pred, obj))
113        g1.add(Literal(subjx), predx, objx)
```

This is the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\msboeres\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_10.1.4.202304151203\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 3489, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\msboeres\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_10.1.4.202304151203\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 3482, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\msboeres\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_10.1.4.202304151203\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 2510, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\msboeres\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_10.1.4.202304151203\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 2517, in _exec
    globals = pydevd_runpy.run_path(file, globals, '__main__')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\msboeres\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_10.1.4.202304151203\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\msboeres\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_10.1.4.202304151203\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\msboeres\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_10.1.4.202304151203\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\prg\ComparaRDFLIB\src\ComparaRDFLIB\ComparaRDFLIB.py", line 113, in <module>
```

The flow stops in a module `latin_1` at line 26:

```
24 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
25     def decode(self, input, final=False):
26         return codecs.latin_1_decode(input,self.errors)[0]
```

Comment: Is there any way to format the code and clean the exception stack up a little more? It's difficult to read as-is (remove line numbers, code on separate lines, call stack messages on new lines, etc). One thing that I noticed is that you should be passing a Tuple to g1.add rather than three parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the help adjusting the code

Comment: How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the add function by passing a tuple in? To me, it looks like you're using the function incorrectly. See on line 112 how you're passing a tuple? Do that with line 113 too.

Comment: I follow your suggestion and the error continues the same

Comment: What is the value of subjx? Can you call Literal(subjx) above line 113 and see if the issue is with Literal() and not add()?